# batch for loop, remove quotas from searchlist

Tags: batch-file

I bet someone can help me fast, didn't found the correct answer/solution over search function, already spent much time now for simple one liner. I need to make a searchlist variable and multiple search elements in it with a batch file.
Example:

```
@Echo Off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set searchlist="_Var1","_Var 2","Var_ 3","File1","varwithspaces = 12","supervar ="
FOR %%R IN (%searchlist%) DO (
echo %%R
)
pause
```

output is:

```
"_Var1"
"_Var 2"
"Var_ 3"
"File1"
"varwithspaces = 12"
"supervar ="
```

but i need this output:

```
_Var1
_Var 2
Var_ 3
File1
varwithspaces = 12
supervar =
```

Please help me, im teh batch noob...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually use the `enabledelayedexpansion` which you have already set. Then Set `%%r` as a variable, then replace `"`

```
@Echo Off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set searchlist="_Var1","_Var 2","Var_ 3","File1","varwithspaces = 12","supervar ="
for %%r in (%searchlist%) DO (
set "var=%%r"
set "var=!var:"=!"
echo !var!
)
endlocal
pause
```

Then to get rid of the double quotes only, without using substring replacement, simply use `~` infront of your variable.

```
@Echo Off
set searchlist="_Var1","_Var 2","Var_ 3","File1","varwithspaces = 12","supervar ="
for %%r in (%searchlist%) DO (
echo %%~r
)
pause
```

Comment: hell yes, so fast! Thank you very much.

Comment: and what about simply `echo %%~r`. see `for /?` for reference substitution

Answer (score 0):

As ***@elzooilogico*** said in his comment : just use `echo %%~R`

```bat
@Echo Off
set searchlist="_Var1","_Var 2","Var_ 3","File1","varwithspaces = 12","supervar ="
FOR %%R IN (%searchlist%) DO (
    echo %%~R
)
pause
```

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [For /?](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) - Conditionally perform a command several times. 
  [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)